# Implement getHeadRotation android panoramic view

Tags: android, google-vr-sdk

I want to get the yaw and pitch of the head just like in the method nativeGetHeadRotation given in class VrPanoramaRenderer of the GVr sdk. I have not been able to just use this method without actually using the VRPanoramaView itself. I create my custom renderer that I attach to a GLSurface, but on every drawFrame I want to check how much the head has moved by and render something.

1. How do I go about implementing getHeadRotation?
2. Should I just follow the getRotationMatrix approach and use the yaw and pitch from that?

Comment: Are you able to do this? I am also in similar situation.

Comment: I went with option 2, but I don't have the code right now since I switched companies.

Comment: ok. Any pointers to look out while implementing this?